# AppleLanguages value overrides the value of language set in IOS settings preferred language

Tags: ios, settings, nslocalizedstring, overriding

I am working on Localization of my app that supports both spanish and English languages.These options are listed in a tableview.On clicking English i am setting the value "en" for the key "AppleLanguages" in NSUserDefaults.So that it can show the content in English.

```
NSUserDefaults *nsdefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [nsdefault setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [nsdefault synchronize];
```

Also at the same time i am trying to fetch the Language programmatically from IOS device which was set at General>>International>>Language manually using code.

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

For the very first time language gives me correct value that has been set.But If i change my option from list like Spanish or English and set value for key "AppleLanguages".It overrides  the value of my device setting language.And from then ownwards i dont get the correct value of language under Setting>>International>>Language.

I want that every time i choose the language manually in settings like Francis etc.I should be able to get the newly set language.I even tried to follow the link by apple.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpinternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a right way to do that and you should not do that.
 You should only rely on the system settings. I gave you one reason for not doing that: all system calls are made with system language. If you force one language such as spanish in an english system and you display a map inside your app you will see all streets etc in english, the same happen if you request reverse geocoding or other system services.

Comment: There are certainly plenty of good reasons to want to override the default system behaviour with regards to the interface language. There is lots of discussion about that online that I won't repeat here, but in my specific case I'm building an English-language learning application where some of our Japanese users indicated they wish to set the user interface language to English (to feel more immerged) while other users prefer to keep it in the default Japanese.  Setting AppleLanguages is probably not the best way to do it. Start here for some other ideas: http://tinyurl.com/ui-language-in-ios

Comment: Thank you for the valuable reference and reasonable reasons