# Force emoji keyboard in html

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm aware there are [multiple input types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) that force different keyboard layouts on mobile devices. Is there an input type or other attribute that will force the input to open to emoji keyboard on focus?

---

I don't believe there is, as emoji is technically another language keyboard. But I'd love outside validation to make sure this is the case.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318076 if you can't do it in natively, you _definitely_ can't do it in a webview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't for now, there was an issue on github about that : https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/495