# In localization, keyboard appears only with English language

Tags: ios, swift, internationalization, ios9.1, iqkeyboardmanager

I am trying to make my app through internationalization and it works pretty well.

I made it in two languages: Turkish and English. But when I run my app in Turkish language, labels and buttons show Turkish language, but when I tap my `UITextField`, instead of showing the keyboard in Turkish language, it appears in English. So, how can I display my keyboard in Turkish language?

I am using `IQKeyboardManager`.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318076/how-to-show-specific-language-keyboard-when-user-input-values-in-uitextfield-in

looks like you won't be able to do it, it's up to user to set their preferred language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can not be done automatically. Go to Settings -> General -> Keyboards. Add the keyboard which you would like to add.

Open the application and tap on text field. Tapping on the Globe Icon on keyboard will allow you to toggle the keyboard.

Programatically it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

you can change localization language if you add this in your info.plist file.

[image]